# Homestead not syncing data with mac

Tags: macos, laravel, virtualbox, homestead, nfs

My VirtualBox is not syncing correctly with my MacBook. When i take a look at my laravel config folder, im missing a file with `view.php`. When i list all files and directories with `ls -lisa` on my virtualbox, i dont see the `views.php`. But when i execute `cat views.php` i see the contents of the file.

Another strange thing is: when i just add `test.php` to the config folder, the `views.php` is visible in my machine. I also figured out that a lot of `vendor` files are missing...

I have a MacBook Pro with Hight Sierra, Vagrant 1.9.7 and VirtualBox 5.0.40. I've installed the vagrant plugin for NFS `vagrant plugin install vagrant-bindfs`. My config file looks like this:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:

    - map: ~/Sites/seo-app.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/seo-app.dev
      type: "nfs"

sites:

    - map: seo-app-local.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/seo-app.dev/public_html

    - map: admin.seo-app-local.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/seo-app.dev/public_html

    - map: api.seo-app-local.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/seo-app.dev/public_html

    - map: client.seo-app-local.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/seo-app.dev/public_html


databases:
    - reviews
    - seo_app

blackfire:
    - id: *************
      token: **********
      client-id: **********
      client-token: ***********

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too. I solved it halting the machine and booting it up with the provision option. Here the commands:

```
$ homestead halt
$ homestead up --provision
```